# Помогите написать регулярное выражение на java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Допустим есть строка `4534%^$!@!Фамилия4534%^$!@! Имя 4534%^$!@!Отчество 4534%^$!@!`

Нужно эту строку заменить через регулярку  на Фамилия Имя Отчество  , т.е чтобы  между словами (Фамилия Имя Отчество) был только один пробел, а до слово Фамилия и после слово Отчество ничего не было вообще(никаких символов никаких пробелом букв и цыфр).

Помогите пожалуйста.     Важно понимать, что вместо Фамилия Имя Отчество могут быть Иван Иван Иванович Артюхин Алексей Петрович и.т.д.

Comment: символы вокруг фамилия, имя и отчество всегда одинаковы?

Comment: нет, они всегда разные.  Важно понимать, что вместо Фамилия Имя Отчество могут быть Иван Иван Иванович Артюхин Алексей Петрович и.т.д.

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan, разные символы? Они повторяются в строке?

Comment: Симовлы разные могут быть (включая пробелы) вокруг и между Фамилия Имя Отчество

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Импортируем пакет:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
```

Удаляем из строки все символы, кроме русских букв и лишние пробелы с конца и начала строки с помощью метода `trim()`:

```
class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String Main = "4534%^$!@!Фамилия4534%^$!@! Имя 4534%^$!@!Отчество 4534%^$!@!";

        String replaced = Main.replaceAll("[^А-Яа-я]+", " ");
        System.out.println(replaced.trim());
    }
}
```

На выходе получаем:

```
Фамилия Имя Отчество
```

Comment: Важно понимать, что вместо Фамилия Имя Отчество могут быть Иванов Иван Иванович Артюхин Алексей Петрович и.т.д.

Comment: Огромное спасибо добрый человек!

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan, всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: Дружище можешь мне контакт какой-нибудь скинуть  мне для разрешения сложных вопросов, обещаю не спамить)!

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan, конечно, [вот](https://vk.com/wnull).